# php multidimension array dynamically

Tags: php, json

This is the static multidimension array and i converted to json.

```
$mailmsg = array(
  'type'=> 'line',
  'data' =>   array(
      'labels' => array("1","2","3","4","5"),  
      'datasets' => array(array("label"=>"A","fill"=>"false","yAxisID"=>"A","borderColor"=>"#bae755","data"=>array(100, 96, 84, 76, 69)),array("label"=>"B","fill"=>"false","yAxisID"=>"B","borderColor"=>"#55bae7","data"=>array(1, 1, 1, 1, 0)),array("label"=>"C","fill"=>"false","yAxisID"=>"C","borderColor"=>"#e755ba","data"=>array(5, 15, 10, 10, 0)))),
  ' '=>array("scales"=>array("yAxes"=>array(array("scaleLabel"=>array("display"=>"true","labelString"=>"Prn1"),"id"=>"A","type"=>"linear","position"=>"left"),array("scaleLabel"=>array("display"=>"true","labelString"=>"Prn2"),"id"=>"B","type"=>"linear","position"=>"left"),array("scaleLabel"=>array("display"=>"true","labelString"=>"Prn3"),"id"=>"C","type"=>"linear","position"=>"left")))
));
echo $json = json_encode((object)$mailmsg, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Result:

```
{
    "type": "line",
    "data": {
        "labels": ["1","2","3","4","5"],
        "datasets": [{
            "label": "A",
            "fill": "false",
            "yAxisID": "A",
            "borderColor": "#bae755",
            "data": [100, 96, 84, 76, 69]
        }, {
            "label": "B",
            "fill": "false",
            "yAxisID": "B",
            "borderColor": "#55bae7",
            "data": [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
        }, {
            "label": "C",
            "fill": "false",
            "yAxisID": "C",
            "borderColor": "#e755ba",
            "data": [5, 15, 10, 10, 0]
        }]
    },
    "options": {
        "scales": {
            "yAxes": [{
                "scaleLabel": {
                    "display": "true",
                    "labelString": "Prn1"
                },
                "id": "A",
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left"
            }, {
                "scaleLabel": {
                    "display": "true",
                    "labelString": "Prn2"
                },
                "id": "B",
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left"
            }, {
                "scaleLabel": {
                    "display": "true",
                    "labelString": "Prn3"
                },
                "id": "C",
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to above static array to change dynamically using foreach.

Comment: Didn't understand the question what do you mean change dynamically

Comment: I have the data sets array separetely. I want to display the expected result by using the individual arrays

Comment: I still don't get it. Maybe you should just describe the results by giving examples, preferably examples that are much smaller than the above, unless that size is really necessary for something.

Answer (score 1):

just pass the reference to the specific data in the array:

```
foreach($mailmsg['data']['datasets'] as $key => $value){

}
```